# How to create query to update records only when changes occur and to add new records that do not already exist

Tags: sql

I am running a query that fetches data(records) form a linked table from another database.
The linked table is populated by users using a form remotely, like the web.

I created this piece of code that queries the data from the linked table into a new table, like this:

```
`INSERT INTO NEW_TBL(ENT_CUS_NUM, ENT_FIRST_NAME, ENT_LAST_NAME, ENT_ADDRESS1, ENT_CITY, ENT_STATE, ENT_ZIP, ENT_PHONE) 

SELECT LINK_TBL.CUS_NUM, LINK_TBL.FIRST_NAME, LINK_TBL.LAST_NAME, LINK_TBL.ADDRESS1, LINK_TBL.CITY, LINK_TBL.STATE, LINK_TBL.ZIP, LINK_TBL.PHONE 

FROM LINK_TBL`
```

Is it possible to modify this query so that it inserts new records from the link table if the record has not already been added, or update existent records
that have been modified? Example: Lets say a person changes their address, Can I update or bring over only their address without re-inserting their entire record because of an address change?

This is what confuses, I could write an update statement but modifying this querying so that it brings over new records or update records with changes is way over my head.

I would appreciate your input and help.

Guy

Comment: Merge or Upsert are the keywords you want to search for. Syntax and availability is db dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can designate a field as a unique key, you can use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO at least with mysql

Comment: I am thinking about using 1 statement to perform both the update and the insert.